# Is there an option in DCC32 to specify output file name

Tags: delphi

Most command line compiler has option (e.g.: `-o`) to specify the output file name.  Is there a similar option in `dcc32.exe`?

For example:

```
dcc32.exe FastMM4.pas -o FastMM4-Test.dcu
```

will compile a `FastMM4-Test.dcu` file.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option. Delphi compiler search used units by name, so file names should match compiled unit names.
I suppose you want to compile multiple FastMM versions using different configuration options. To do so, you should use "Build configurations" feature from the "Project manager" window. For example, you can create additional "CustomFastMM" configuration (right click on "Build configurations", and select "New configuration"). Then you can edit this new config to set up additional DEFINEs, compilation options and output directories (right click and select "Edit").
Also note that you can create "child" configuration by right click on existing config and select "Create configuration". "Child" configs inherits all options from its "Parent" by default, but you can edit them to override some options or add additional DEFINEs.

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution works but I still prefer using `dcc32` to compile due to it's simplicity.

Comment: I am too using dcc32 directly in my build scenarios for older Delphi versions, and using -N0 compiler flag to put the compiled DCUs to the configuration-specific folder. Dont forget to use -U flag to include this folder to compiler search paths:
    dcc32 myunit.pas -U c:\Project\Config1 -N0 c:\Project\Config1

Answer (score 0):

To give a more complete picture of the situation, note that:

1. There is option -E"path" that allows you to choose the directory in which the compiled exe/dll will be saved.
2. There is option -N"path" that allows you to choose where the DCU files will be saved.

By default the output files will be saved in the same folder as the sources.